# Check closed set and compact property for subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, upper-lower-bounds

I am given some subsets of $\mathbb{R}$:
 1. $M_a := ]-\infty ,0]$
 2. $M_b := [-1 ,0[$
 3. $M_c := \mathbb{N}$
 4. $M_d := \{\frac1n |n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
 5. $M_e := [-1,0] \cup M_d$

I need to check if those subsets are:
 - bounded
 - closed
 - compact
(and to proove my assumptions)

The bounded property seems almost obvious to me, I know it depends on upper and lower bounds (e.g. sup and inf), but does the set need to have both inf and sup to be bounded, or only one of them is sufficient to be called bounded?  As for the closed and compact proeprties, I am not very sure what's meant with it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read carefully the definitions again, before attempting problems that assume you know them.

Comment: By definition, bounded ( in $\mathbb{R}$ ) means that for all $x$ in the set, you can find $M>0$ so that $\left|x\right| \leq M$. It should help you to understand that $M_{a}$ is not bounded whereas $M_{b}$ is bounded. What about the three others ?

Comment: Then $M_c$ is not bounded and $M_d$ and $M_e$ are bounded, if I understood it right.  
I read the definition of compact sets (@uniquesolution yes I know I am really lazy, I should have done this before), and it says, a set is compact, if it's bounded and closed. But I don't really get the *closed* property definition